# Create Frame depending on the purpose of the button

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

On the form:
* TCategoryButtons (for example, there are 3 categories in each of which 10 buttons)
* TPageControl (clean)
Created 30 (for example) different frames.

It is necessary when pressing the button:
1. Check whether a frame has already been created (only one frame for one button).
2. Create a tab in TPageControl and activate it.
3. Create a frame corresponding to the button and put it into the created tab (if the tab is closed, kill it and the frame).

That's what I could do:

```
procedure TForm1.CategoryButtons1Categories0Items0Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Client: TTabSheet;
begin
  if (not Assigned(Frame2)) then
  begin
    Client := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
    Client.PageControl := PageControl1;
    Client.Caption := CategoryButtons1.Categories[0].Items[0].Caption;
    PageControl1.ActivePage := Client;

    Frame2 := TFrame2.Create(nil);
    Frame2.Parent := Client;
  end;
end;
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
type
  TFrameClass = class of tframe; 

function GetFrClass(const aClassID: Integer): TFrameClass;
begin
  case aClassID of
    1:
      Result := TFrame2;
    2:
      Result := TFrame3;
  else
    Result := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateFrm(tags: Integer; NameTSh: string);
var
  FrClass: TFrameClass;
  Frame: tframe;
  Client: TTabSheet;
begin
  FrClass := GetFrameClass(tags);

  if (FrClass <> nil) then
  begin
    Client := TTabSheet.Create(Self);
    Client.PageControl := PageControl1;
    Client.Caption := NameTSh;

    Frame := FrClass.Create(Client);
    Frame.Parent := Client;
  end;
end;
```

But this method does not limit the number of frame instances created.

Please tell me the solution!

Comment: Surely, all you need to do is to check whether an instance of the frame class in question has already been added and abort the creation of a new one if it has?

Comment: @MartynA It is necessary to check whether the frame exists or not, if yes, then show the message, otherwise create it. And the ability to destroy the created frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tags: Integer` value in procedure `TForm1.CreateFrm()` to determine whether a frame already exists in `PageControl1` or not.

Before you create a frame and add it to the `PageControl1`, check if any of the existing pages already has the value of `tags` in the `tag` property:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateFrm(tags: Integer; NameTSh: string);
var
  i: integer;
  ...
begin
  for i := 0 to PageControl1.PageCount-1 do
    if PageControl1.Pages[i].tag = tags then
      Exit;

  FrClass := GetFrameClass(tags);
  ...
```

At the end of the `CreateFrm()` procedure you store `tags`

```
  PageControl1.Pages[PageControl1.PageCount-1].Tag := tags;
end;
```

Comment: Cool! Everything worked out. But the question remains how to close frames.

Comment: Closing decided by adding an array - Frames: array [0 .. 29] of TFrame;